# The original standard error estimation of Fama and French (2015) paper

Tags: regression, fama-french, econometrics

I have a question about the estimation method of the original paper of Fama and French (2015) regarding the five factor model and the t statistics. Are they using non-robust standard errors or are they using the HAC standard errors? In the paper Fama and French (1993) they argue that they use the method of Black et al., (1972) for their time series regression but i could not find if they apply the HAC method for the standard errors or just the standard errors of an ordinary least square regression estimation.